# How to reload data in parent UITableViewController from Modal ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a navigation controller with a root view controller (UITableViewController).  This table view controller has a modal segue to another navigation controller with a UITableViewController as the root view controller.  From my modal table view controller, I am calling

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to dismiss the model view.  I am trying to, prior to dismissing the modal view, call my "refresh" function (which is located in the first UITableViewController).  I tried using

```
[self.parentViewController refresh];
```

but I am guessing that I am then referring to the navigation controller of the modal view?  It doesn't seem to be working for that reason.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create an [`NSNotificationCenter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in your parent view:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refresh) name:@"updateParent" object:nil];
```

Then call it when you dismiss the modal view:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateParent" object:nil];
```

Comment: Sweet! Worked like a charm! Thanks so much!